# Auto-Increment editable Column

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-migration, auto-increment, identity-column

I am looking for the best solution, of a problem I've met.

I have several databases, which I align quite often to have the same data in it. In some referential tables there are Auto-Increment ID columns, and in other tables there are columns that match these ID values. Unfortunately, on the source DB IDs after changes might be like: (10,15,20), while, after inserting it into destination table it is (1,2,3). I hope my mock-ups clarify the situation:

Source DB RefTable:

```
ID_________Name
10_________a
15_________b
20_________c
```

Destination DB RefTable:

```
ID_________Name
1__________a
2__________b
3__________c
```

Source FactTable:

```
RefTableID___OtherColumns
10__________a
10__________b
15__________c
15__________d
```

The problem is that after migrating FactTable to the destination DB it does not match records from the RefTable. I had an idea to add another column that will be editable in contrast to ID column. The issue is that the end-user should not see it (it will not mean anything for him), so it should be also auto-increment. What should I use in this situation:

- sequence?
- -trigger?
- -post add/save stored procedure?

Or maybe someone has better idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: Why do you use on the destination database auto-increment? The database is updated from other source as well?

Comment: Yes. Generally, there is one database that is just to develop and another for en end-user, so in the future, only the second one will be important

Comment: Try switching identity_insert on and after the update is made back to off.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server, an identity columns can't be updated once the row was inserted into a table.

However, it's value can be inserted manually by using [`set identity_insert`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-identity-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) for the specified table.
In each session, you can have only a single table with `identity_insert` set to `on` at the same time, so always set it back to `off` once insert is complete.

The code might look something like this:

```
set identity_insert RefTable on;

insert into RefTable (id, name)
select id, name
from sourceDb.sourceSchema.RefTable s
where not exists (
    select 1
    from RefTable t
    where t.Id = s.Id
);

set identity_insert RefTable off;
```